# Building NodeJs module with boost (or any other library for that matter)

Tags: c++, node.js, boost, module

I'm trying to build a nodejs module with C++ and Ubuntu 13.04 using some boost headers as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <node/node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>



using namespace std;
using namespace v8;


Handle<Value> Method(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;

  std::string foobar = "8";

  return scope.Close(String::New("world"));
}

void init(Handle<Object> exports){

    exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("Hello"),
            FunctionTemplate::New(Method)->GetFunction());

}

NODE_MODULE(hello, init)
```

However, when compiling with node-gyp, I get the following errors:

> sam@ubuntu:~/workspace_cpp/NodeTest/src$ node-gyp build gyp info it
>   worked if it ends with ok gyp info using node-gyp@0.10.9 gyp info
>   using node@0.10.15 | linux | x64 gyp info spawn make gyp info spawn
>   args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ] make: Entering directory
>   `/home/sam/workspace_cpp/NodeTest/src/build'   CXX(target)
>   Release/obj.target/hello/NodeTest.o In file included from
>   /usr/include/boost/numeric/conversion/converter.hpp:14:0,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/numeric/conversion/cast.hpp:33,
>                    from /usr/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:66,
>                    from ../NodeTest.cpp:13: /usr/include/boost/numeric/conversion/converter_policies.hpp: In
>   member function ‘void
>   boost::numeric::def_overflow_handler::operator()(boost::numeric::range_check_result)’:
>   /usr/include/boost/numeric/conversion/converter_policies.hpp:162:31:
>   error: exception handling disabled, use -fexceptions to enable make:
>   *** [Release/obj.target/hello/NodeTest.o] Error 1 make: Leaving directory`/home/sam/workspace_cpp/NodeTest/src/build' gyp ERR! build
>   error  gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2 gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.onExit
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17) gyp ERR!
>   stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
>   (child_process.js:789:12) gyp ERR! System Linux 3.8.0-19-generic gyp
>   ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "build" gyp ERR! cwd
>   /home/sam/workspace_cpp/NodeTest/src gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.15 gyp
>   ERR! node-gyp -v v0.10.9 gyp ERR! not ok

I cannot find anything on the web for how to get node-gyp to build with other libraries such as boost.  Does anybody have any insight or experience with this?  My ultimate goal is to make a SOAP module using gsoap.

**EDIT**
I'm assuming that I have to edit my binding.gyp file in some way to allow for boost to be compiled.  As it sits, this file currently looks like this:

```
{   "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "hello",
      "sources": [ "NodeTest.cpp" ]
    }   ] }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  The text copied kinda goofy.

Comment: did you manage to use gsoap, I came to the same problem and currently looking into that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anybody else that has this error, the key is enabling exceptions for node-gyp.  In your bindings.gyp file, make sure you include this

```
...
'cflags!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ],
'cflags_cc!': [ '-fno-exceptions' ]
...
```

I found my solution in this forum post: [GitHub](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp/issues/17)