# Why is GLFW3 failing to link symbols when building with nw-gyp but not VS2019

Tags: node.js, c++17, node-modules, vulkan, node-webkit

I'm trying to use Vulkan in a C++ Node.js plugin to use with NW.js. using the VS2019 Local debugger, the program builds and runs fine but when building with node-gyp or specifically, nw-gyp. GLFW3 fails to link several of its functions.

[image: Linker Errors]

due to GLFW3 being a C library, Ive also applied the working around for MSVS listed here: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2250 GLFW3 has the extern "C" macro by default in its header file. its wrapped in the "_cplusplus" but MSVC seem to support it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170
if I'm not mistaken the errors seem to have "mangled" symbols names which isn't supposed to happen in C.
apart from that I've tried:

1. Rearranging the order libraries are listed in the Gyp file, just in case its a load order issue.
2. specifying C++17 , as the Vulkan API seems to use it in their tutorial.
3. Use absolute paths for all libraries except for the node api.
4. specify to use MSVC2015.
5. remove everything except for GLFW3, leaving 1 call to GLFW3 to ensure the compiler doesn't remove it.
6. Make an empty project containing only the very first Vulkan setup (Windows) seen here: https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment
7. Adding the "fno-exception' flags from this answer: [Building NodeJs module with boost (or any other library for that matter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139466/building-nodejs-module-with-boost-or-any-other-library-for-that-matter)

Below is my binding.gyp

[image]

vulkTest.cpp, contains the Vulkan test code identical to that listen on the Vulkan website. index.cpp is empty, testGreeting.cpp contains a function that simply returns a std::string.

I'm using the MSVC compiler, Visual Studio 2019. Windows 10. I can only guess that for whatever reason GLFW3 is being treated as a C++ library despite the measures taken to prevent that.

nw-gyp: https://github.com/nwjs/nw-gyp

GLFW3: https://github.com/glfw/glfw

NW.js is version 29.4 : https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js

If I missed something, Ill happily add the required information.

Answer (score 0):

One easy thing to try is to set your global Node version to match the same one built in to NW.js.

In your case, you are using NW.js 0.29.4, which comes with Node 9.11.1.

- https://nwjs.io/versions.json

If you have Node globally installed already, I'd uninstall it, then install `nvm-windows` and use that to install and switch to that version of Node.js.

- https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases
- `nvm install 9.11.1 && nvm use 9.11.1`

Also make sure you have Python 2 installed. I'm pretty sure if you have `C:\Python27` added to your PATH you're fine. But you may want to google that if you have Python 3 also.

Then delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and try `npm install` again.

More details on NW-GYP:

- https://dev.to/thejaredwilcurt/guide-to-nw-js-versions-5d38#0392-20190627

If that doesn't work, then I'm not sure what the issue could be, this is just a good first thing to try.

Comment: I do infact have both Python 3 and 2 installed. nw-gyp's "--python" setting is broken and doesn't actually do anything, so i removed Python 3 from PATH before attempting to use it. jsut to be sure ive also added this to gyp_main.py

`import warnings

#check python version, as Python 3 breaks nw-gyp
if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    warn_message = "WARNING: Python 3 detected!! Version is" + str(sys.version_info[0])
    warnings.warn(warn_message)`

Comment: it seem to be running Python 2.7. 

I had nvm installed already. Unfortunately rolling back to node.js 9.11.1 and reinstalling nw-gyp did not fix the issue